# Finding the states with the three most populous counties

Tags: python, performance, beginner, csv, pandas

I just started to use Python and Pandas. My current solution to a problem looks ugly and inefficient. I would like to know how to improve it. Data file is Census 2010 can be viewed [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/words-sdsc/coursera/master/big-data-2/csv/census.csv)

Question:

> Only looking at the three most populous counties for each state, what are the three most populous states (in order of highest population to lowest population)? Use CENSUS2010POP.
>   This function should return a list of string values.

Current code

```
def answer_six():
    cdf = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
    cdf = cdf.groupby('STNAME')
    cdf = cdf.apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('CENSUS2010POP', ascending=False)).reset_index(drop=True)
    cdf = cdf.groupby('STNAME').head(3)
    cdf = cdf.groupby('STNAME').sum()
    cdf = cdf.sort_values('CENSUS2010POP', axis=0, ascending=False).head(3)
    return list(cdf.index)
```

Answer (score 6):

[nlargest](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) could help, it finds the maximum n values in pandas series.

In this line of code, groupby groups the frame according to state name, then apply finds the 3 largest values in column CENSUS2010POP and sums them up. The resulting series has the unique state names as index and the corresponding top 3 counties sum, applying nlargest gets a series with the top 3 states as required

```
return census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50].groupby(
    'STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].apply(
    lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum()).nlargest(
    3).index.values.tolist()
```

Comment: You should explain a little bit more about the function you're suggesting.

Answer (score 6):

[`SUMLEV` is explained here](http://blog.cubitplanning.com/2011/03/census-summary-level-sumlev/)

Definitely want to use [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)
The advantage of `nlargest` is that it performs a partial sort therefore in linear time.

However, you don't want to `groupby` twice.  So we'll define a helper function in which we only `groupby` once.

I'm using a lot of `.values` to access underlying `numpy` objects.  This will improve some efficiency a bit.

Lastly, I don't like accessing names from the outer scope without a purpose so I'm passing the dataframe as a parameter.

```
def answer_six(df):
    # subset df to things I care about
    sumlev = df.SUMLEV.values == 50
    data = df[['CENSUS2010POP', 'STNAME', 'CTYNAME']].values[sumlev]

    # build a pandas series with State and County in the index
    # vaues are from CENSUS2010POP
    s = pd.Series(data[:, 0], [data[:, 1], data[:, 2]], dtype=np.int64)

    # define a function that does the nlargest and sum in one
    # otherwise you'd have to do a second groupby
    def sum_largest(x, n=3):
        return x.nlargest(n).sum()

    return s.groupby(level=0).apply(sum_largest).nlargest(3).index.tolist()
```

***Demonstration***

```
answer_six(census_df)

['California', 'Texas', 'Illinois']
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50].groupby(
>     'STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].apply(
>     lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum()).nlargest(
>     3).index.values.tolist()
> ```

Above: This seems to be the best way to do it. Below: I found another way that is slightly less elegant, but it helped me understand why sgDysregulation's solution works. I hope it can help you also.

```
census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50].groupby(
    'STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].nlargest(3).groupby(
    'STNAME').sum().nlargest(3).index.values.tolist()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.